# Git: how to revert a branch merge without overwriting history?

Tags: git, merge, branch, revert

I have two branches: `master` and `opengl`. I recently finished implementation (or at least I thought so) of `opengl` branch and decided to merge it into `master`:

```
git checkout master
git merge opengl
git push
```

After I did this, several developers who are working on the `master` branch pulled my changes and it turned out that my implementation conflicted with some of their code. Therefore I would like to revert the merge operation on the `master` branch, but without overwriting history.

Note that I would like to be able to merge the `opengl` branch into `master` eventually (after I fix all the bugs). Therefore simply checking out older version of `master` and committing it will not work - newly created commit will cancel my changes from `opengl` when I will try to merge it.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt helps?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation "[How to revert a faulty merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)" mentioned by [cebewee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647987/cebewee) explains why a git revert is tricky when reverting a merge.

> So **the merge will still exist**, and it will still be seen as joining the two branches together, and future merges will see that merge as the last shared state - and the revert that reverted the merge brought in will not affect that at all.
>   If you think of "revert" as "undo", then you're going to always miss this part of reverts.
>   Yes, it undoes the data, but no, it doesn't undo history.

`git revert` is the right solution here, but it will have a consequence in the future, when you want to merge that branch again.
The next merge will then have to "revert the revert" first, and then merge the branch.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize the last two phrases, because they are very important (and easy to miss and then do not understand the consequences of not reverting the revert commit.)

Comment: See also https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html, which has a "Reverting the Revert" section

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** This turns out *not* to be what the OP asked for, but I'll keep it here in case someone should happen to look for a solution that *does* involve rewriting history.

---

First, create a new branch if you want to keep the merge commit locally, so that the commit doesn't "disappear" after you move `master`:

```
git branch erroneousMerge master
```

*If the other developers have also made commits after the erroneous merge, they must do this as well!*

Then, reset `master` to refer to the last commit before the merge; let's say that it's commit `e498b2...`:

```
git checkout e498b2
git branch -f master
```

Now, you can push the corrected `master` (`-f` indicates that you want to make the server reset its `master` branch to the commit that you have made it point to, even though this commit is an ancestor of the one it points to in the repository):

```
git push -f origin master
```

Now, the other developers can update their `master` to match that of the server(`-f` indicates that they accept that the branch has moved backwards):

```
git fetch -f origin master:master
```

If the other developers have made changes after the erroneous merge (let's say that the merge commit is `abc123`, they can use `rebase` to move the changes to the corrected `master`:

```
git rebase --onto master abc123 oldMaster
```

If you screw up at some point and end up with "losing" commits because there is no longer any branches pointing to them, you can use `git fsck --lost-found` to recover them.

Comment: What you are suggesting is exactly overwriting history. I would like to avoid this, because there are too many people who are using repository and all of them will have to perform this operation. I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: You could create a new commit that reverses the effects of the merge commit by using [`git revert`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) (also described in the link @cebewee posted).